# What else is required to allow CORS on incoming requests in Angular 2/4 app on S3 buckets

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, amazon-s3

We've an Angular 2/4 web app running on AWS S3 buckets. We wanted to allow any ***** 3<sup>rd</sup> party website to access it's assets viz. `.css`, `.js`, `.images` etc.

[image: Enable CORS in Angular 2/4]

The 3<sup>rd</sup> party website is supposed to embed a code like this:

```
<script src="http://angular2-4-app.domain/widget.js"></script>
```

The `widget.js` file internally calls other assets viz. `.css`, `.js`, `.images` etc.

For example:

```
var n=document.createElement("script");
n.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
n.setAttribute("src","folder1/asset1.js");
n.async="async";
```

The green line represent the requests in which the assets are served back to the 3rd party website which is **not happening currently**.

The red line represent the requests in which the assets are not served back to the 3rd party website which is **happening currently** because of CORS issues.

We wanted to achieve the green line requests.

The CORS seems to be enabled on them from the AWS console:

[image: CORS allowed on AWS]

We need a solution like [CORS in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622564/2404470)

What else is required to enable CORS in this case?

Comment: Unless you are trying to access those resources with XHR/fetch/canvas, then you shouldn't need CORS at all. There are no cross-origin restrictions on using images in `<img>`, JS in `<script>` etc.

Comment: "The red line represent the requests in which the assets are not served back to the 3rd party website which is happening currently because of CORS issues." — How is the third party website trying to load the resources? What is the *exact* error message that is displayed in the console that leads you to think this has something to do with CORS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this CORS Common Request Header:

```
<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
```

[Common Request Headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonRequestHeaders.html)

Basically the way you have your CORS policy written is that the only header supported is Authorization. Example:

```
Authorization: AWS AWSAccessKeyId:Signature
```

The solution is to change it to:

```
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

Comment: The solution is correct, but I think this is reversed: 
 *"Basically the way you have your CORS policy written is that all requests require the Authorization header to be present."*   I believe it actually requires that no *other* headers be present.  *"The `AllowedHeader` element specifies which headers are allowed in a preflight request through the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header. Each header name in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header must match a corresponding entry in the rule."*

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. Thank you. I changed the wording in my answer.